# Android ActivityGroup Screen Orientation

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation, activitygroup

I am facing a serious issue and i cant find any answers for on the internet. In my application i have an activity group which contains four activities. In the activity which extends activity group i haven't specified the screen orientation code fragment,

`setRequestedOrientation(1);` 
 And in the other 3 activities i have mentioned it to be portrait. And all the activities works fine in portrait mode. But i need one activity to change the orientation when the device rotates. For that activity i havent specified the setRequestedOrientation(1) code. But That activity does not change according to the device rotation.

Has anyone came across an error like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said, you have `ActivityGroup` and it contains 4 activities, you are setting **Portrait mode** to all the activities except one.

Now, I am sure its happening due to your `ActivityGroup` is having Portrait setting in `AndroidManifest` file, if you remove then your whole `ActivityGroup` would be working in both the orientation. If you keep it as Portrait or Landscape then your sub-activities (i.e. Views) will be in the same orientation as your `ActivityGroup` has.

Answer (score 2):

In the Android Manifest file, go to Application tab, in that select your activity file. You see the attributes on right side. In that you have the Screen orientation option. There you can set your required orientation.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is correct. just add this in your AndroidManifest.xml file in your

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

for the activities that should be in portrait mode.

for landscape just give as

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

if you didn't specify anything the application will work in both landscape and portrait modes.